# Why is p-column called so many times in primeng?

Tags: javascript, primeng

I am trying to call a function within styleClass within a p-column but it is called MANY times... way more than I could have imagined. Can someone please explain to me how this functionality is supposed to work?

Here is an example of what I am doing (I have 20 p-columns but only showed a couple here):

```
<p-datatable #dt [value]="mydata" var="dataRow" class="ui-g-6" [reorderableColumns]="true" columnResizeMode="fit" [resizableColumns]="true" [globalFilter]="tableSearch" [(selection)]="selectedArray" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" [contectMenu]="tableContextMenu" rowGroupMode="rowspan" sortField="dataSource" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="400px" columnResize="expand" [responsive]="true">
    <p-column selectionMode="multiple" styleClass="selectBoxColumn"></p-column>
    <p-column field="name" header="Site Name" [sortable]="true" styleClass="{{changeColor(mydata)}}></p-column>
    <p-column field="index" header="Site Index" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
</p-datatable>
```

I was expecting it to loop through the p-columns once for each row. Therefore `changeColor` would have been called 3 times (once for each row I have). However, its called well over 200 times! My total number of columns is 20 and I only have 3 rows of data.

Can someone please explain why `changeColor` is called so many times? Is there any way to limit it?

I am trying to set a color for that column based on its value. I handle this within `changeColor` and return the color to the class.

On initial load of the page I can see colors start to appear but they are then erased. Im guessing because `changeColor` is called so many times.

UPDATE: I wouldnt care so much about the number of times `changeColor` is called if I could get the colors to return right. Here is an example in `changeColor`:

```
if (localName == "Atlanta") {
    console.log("Chose Atlanta!");
    return 'blue';
} else {
    return 'red';
}
```

I can see the console.log print out "Chose Atlanta!" two times for the two Atlanta rows. However, the columns are all colored red. Again, Im guessing for all the extra times this function is called the column name is not Atlanta so it defaults to red. Very odd!

Comment: I think you should use turbotable

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see if columns behave differently... I think thats just <p-table>, right?

Comment: Ok... I switched over to <p-table>. I can see the results but when I look at my console.log entries I can see that the javascript function, changeColor, is still called many many times.  I now call it like this: <td class="{{changeColor(mydata)}}>{{doc.name}}</td> It returns the color I want three times - but I guess it gets wiped out since its called so many other times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... folks... this was weird but here is what was happening. When I called `changeColor` I was passing in the data for the row `mydata`. I had a console.log in `changeColor` that wrote out this data. I could see it wrote it out 3 times for the 3 rows I had. For all the other times it was called it just wrote out an empty array.
A co-worker suggested I just pass in the value I want to check for. So... I my line now looks like this (for the new turbotable model):

```
<td [ngClass]="changeColor(doc.name)">
   {{doc.name}}
</td>
```

Now that I only pass in the value I want instead of the entire row... it now works! I dont really understand why passing in the entire row caused it to loop so many times.. but that was it!
Thanks to everyone who looked at this!